# What does this in this snippet?

Tags: javascript, symbols

I am reading You Don't Know JS: ES6 & Beyond and I encountered this snippet in Symbol.species section.

```js
class Cool {
    // defer `@@species` to derived constructor
    static get [Symbol.species]() { return this; }

    again() {
        return new this.constructor[Symbol.species]();
    }
}

class Fun extends Cool {}

class Awesome extends Cool {
    // force `@@species` to be parent constructor
    static get [Symbol.species]() { return Cool; }
}

var a = new Fun(),
    b = new Awesome(),
    c = a.again(),
    d = b.again();

c instanceof Fun;           // true
d instanceof Awesome;       // false
d instanceof Cool;          // true
```

It seems like the function Symbol.species{ return Something } should always return a constructor function. But in the first presence of this function:
`static get [Symbol.species]() { return this; }`
I am confused because I always think this should be an object instead of a constructor function.
Could you please help me to clarify the facts?

And about `return new this.constructor[Symbol.species]();`, what does this here refer to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`this` will refer to something different inside a method depending on the context it was executed.

In class methods, static methods, `this` will refer to the class.

So for instance with

```
static get [Symbol.species]() { return this; }
```

Since this is a class method, it will is executed on the class and `this` will refer to the class

```
//since this is a getter we don't use trailing `()`
Cool[Symbol.species] === Cool;
//It does not exist on instances
var myCool = new Cool();
console.log( myCool[Symbol.species] );
//will give undefined
```

Now for instance methods, like the `again` method, they only exist on the instance and so are called from the instance and not the class:

```
console.log( Cool.again );
//will give undefined
var myCool = new Cool();
var newInstance = myCool.again();
```

In instance methods `this` refers to the instance, not the class.

So given:

```
 return new this.constructor[Symbol.species]();
```

- `this` is the instance (eg, `new Cool`)
- `this.constructor` is the constructor that created the instance (eg, `Cool`)
- `this.constructor[Symbol.species]` is the class getter method `Symbol.species`
- `new this.constructor[Symbol.species]()` is a new instance of the class that Symbol.species returned

So the whole line is returning a new instance of a class that the static getter `Symbol.species` method returns.

This allows a class to have methods that create new instances of a class without knowing its name.

So as the example shows, even though `Fun` never defined it's own `again` method `again` knows how to create a new instance of `Fun`. And as `Awesome` shows you can just override Symbol.species to change what instance `again` will create.